# Android onBackPressed() inside a method

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity class and inside there are some methods. And I want to implement the `onBackPressed()` inside the `method2` because I have an important variable that I want to free. I can't/don't make this variable with bigger scope and I can't free this variable inside the method2 because I want to terminate the application and the execution of method 2 with the pressing back button.

```
public  class example extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        method1();
    }

    public method 1 {
        //take some input and assign in a variable.
        method2(variable); 
    }

    public method2 {
        // do something with the variable that take before at method 1
        // and finally press back button
        onBackPressed(){}
        //free variable , finish ();
    }
}
```

As you know i can't Override the `onBackPressed()` inside the method only out at the activity area. Can you provide me a solution for this.

Comment: implemeting onBackPressed means you are going to finish your activity or you want to go to background or something else. Can you explain why you want to do this ??

Answer (score 5):

You should override the `onBackPressed()` method in the activity scope and call it from your method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Do your things.
}

public void method()
{
    onBackPressed();
}
```

If you want to add some complex logic in the `onBackPressed` method, just create another one with parameters.

```
public void myOnBackPressed(int param1, String param2)
{
    // Do your complex logic.
    onBackPressed();
}

public void method()
{
    myOnBackPressed(myInt, myString);
}
```

Comment: Do you need more explanations ?